# How to store and pass on my SAS result value?

Tags: sas

I would like to make decisions based on a dataset like this:

```
data cat;
input type ind;
datalines;
1 0
2 0
3 1
;
run;
```

The decision criterion are: if the minimum of `ind` is 0, then do action A; if the number of observations is 2, then do action B.

```
proc means data=cat N min;
var ind;
run;
```

Now I have printed out the `N` and `min`, which are what I want. But how to extract these values? In R, I can just use `$`, but in SAS it seems that I can only print them out in a table and store them as a dataset, not an independent variable.

Also, better not to use `sql`.

Comment: For conditional logic like this you'll likely need to jump into macros or merge your data depending on what exactly the next steps are.

Comment: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/seminars/sas-macros-introduction/

Comment: Variables only exist in datasets.  Please show an actual example of what you want to do.  Depending on what you want to do you might have to use code generation. SAS has a macro processor language that can help with code generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Reeza, I got my problem solved using macro symput.

```
proc means data=cat N min;
var ind;
output out=decider N=ntotal min=minimum;
run;

data _null_;
  set decider;
  call symput('ntotal', ntotal);
  call symput('minimum',minimum);
run;
```

Comment: You probably do not want to use the older `call symput()` function.  Instead use the newer more powerful `call symputx()` function.

Comment: Thanks, will look at that.@Tom